# I have two Message Listeners listening for the same message. How do I ensure one listener executes its code before the other?

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, protocol-buffers

I have a proto message

Item.proto:

```
   Message SetItemThing {
       required string id;
    }
```

CreateTableListener:

```
public void onMessage(SetItemThing msg) {
   // Creates a table to put items in
}
```

CreateItemInTableListener:

```
public void onMessage(SetItemThing msg) {
   // Puts item in a table that is going to be created
}
```

I want to make sure that CreateTableListener's function runs before CreateItemInTableListener. Since they are getting the same message I was wondering if there was a way to force a CreateTableListener to run first?

If not, what would be the best way to get the desired functionality that I want? 
I was thinking about just making another message and send it a different time but I even if I did, I want to send these messages during the startup phase of my application so I could still get the same problem of not having CreateTableListener go first.

Answer (score 0):

Create a wrapper. The first receiver receives the wrapper, and it checks what the wrapper contains. If it contains create table operation, it execute. If it contains create item operation, it simply fires unwraps and fires it back. The second listener listens for the second operation only.
The akka framework uses somewhat similar concept. It has a supervisor activity and child activities. If the child can execute the task, it executes, if it does not know how to handle the message it returns it back to the supervisor. Then the supervisor sends it to the next activity. Eventually one that knows how to process it processes it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why a message should trigger a DB table create event, but anyway.

If you want async messages to trigger a sequence of actions, first pass the message to step 1, then pass it to step 2. You can do that by creating another queue that only step 2 will listen to.